# How to implement string manipulation in efficienct way?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a string ="/show/search/All.aspx?Att=A1". How to get the last value after the 'Att=' in efficient way ?

Comment: Accept answers to your old questions please. Otherwise, you won't get much response.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a split on the '=' character.

Example (in C#):

string line = "/show/search/All.aspx?Att=A1";

string[] parts = line.Split('=');

//parts[1] contains A1;

Hope this helps

Comment: This only works for his specific instance of the string and breaks if there are other parameters passed in a different order.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only dealing with this one URL then both of the other answers would work fine. I would consider using the [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx#Y600) method and just pull out the item you want by key.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever an

> efficient way

is...
Try this:

```
 var str = "/show/search/All.aspx?Att=A1";
 var searchString = "Att=";
 var answer = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(searchString) + searchString.Length);
```